# Can't make BigCommerce API call in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, e-commerce, bigcommerce

I get

> 'underlying connection was closed'

when running the code below. I am using vb.net 2012 (I must use this version) with the RestSharp library and am trying to retrieve product data from a bigcommerce.com store. This is a simple vb.net 2012 console program that once I get working I can build upon. I have tried changing around the code somewhat even making certain things redundant like the method and URL but I can't get it to work.

```
Dim client As New RestClient
client.BaseUrl = New Uri("https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/mystorehash/v3/catalog/products")

Dim request As New RestRequest("https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/mystorehash/v3/catalog/products", Method.GET)
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Client", "notactualvaluenotactualvalue")
request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token", "notactualvaluenotactualvalue")
request.Method = Method.GET

Dim response As New RestResponse
response = client.ExecuteAsGet(request, Method.GET)

Console.WriteLine("response.Content=" & response.Content)
Console.WriteLine("response.ErrorMessage=" & response.ErrorMessage)
Console.WriteLine("response.ResponseStatus=" & response.ResponseStatus)
Console.WriteLine("response.IsSuccessful=" & response.IsSuccessful)
Console.WriteLine("response.Headers.Count=" & response.Headers.Count)
```

Output:

Any help would be appreciated, hopefully I'm doing something stupid that can be easily fixed

Comment: What is your output? What is the HTTP code you get?

Comment: It almost feels like an authentication failure. You are positive that your X-Auth-Token is correct / current?

Comment: The X-Auth-Token is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that finds this the full implementation of Nathan Booker's suggestion is below. When you attempt to access the Big Commerce api in a VB.NET application you need to specify TLS 1.2. If you don't you'll recieve an HTTP status of `502 - System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.` The solve is done like:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/<Redacted>/v3/catalog/products"), HttpWebRequest)
request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.Accept = "application/json"
request.Method = "GET"
request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Client", "<Redacted>")
request.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "<Redacted>")
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((CType(response, HttpWebResponse)).StatusDescription)
Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
reader.Close()
response.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to your HTTP version or (more likely) SSL/TLS protocol.

If possible, please make sure you're using HTTP 1.1 and TLS 1.2.